# How to use list from sys/queue.h?

Tags: c, linux, list, bsd

Currently, I have implemented a singly linked list, like so:

```
struct PeerNode {
     struct Peer* cargo;
     struct PeerNode* next;
};
```

...and I have a struct that contains a couple of these linked lists, like so:

```
struct Torrent {
     ...
     struct PeerNode* peer_list;
     struct PeerNode* unchoked_peers;
     ...
}
```

I would like to replace this by using the macros provided by `sys/queue.h`. I gather that I could replace my code with something like this:

```
struct Torrent {
     ...
     LIST_ENTRY(PeerNode, Peer) peer_list;
     struct PeerNode* unchoked_peers;
     ...
}
```

Then, from looking at `man queue`, I believe I would initialize the lists by doing something like this:

```
LIST_INIT(&peer_list);
LIST_INIT(unchoked_peers);
```

However, I don't understand how `LIST_ENTRY` factors into usage of the list. From the `man` page, it says: "The macro `LIST_ENTRY` declares a structure that connects the elements in the list," but I don't really understand what this means.

Why would I want to declare a structure to connect the elements in the list? Shouldn't each node be connected to the next node via a pointer, like my initial linked list implementation? How would I replace my linked lists with the implementation provided by `sys/queue.h`? How would I insert an element into the list?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

LIST_ENTRY creates fields to put into your structure that are suitable for linking the elements, so you do not have to concern yourself with the specifics of those pointers.

```
struct foo {
    int a, b, c;
    /* This is instead of "struct foo *next" */
    LIST_ENTRY(foo) pointers;
};
```

To then create a list you'd use LIST_HEAD():

```
struct Torrent {
    LIST_HEAD(foo_list, foo) bar;
};
```

You can initialise the list header using LIST_INIT():

```
struct Torrent t;
LIST_INIT(&t.bar);
```

You can insert elements using the LIST_INSERT_*() macros:

```
struct foo *item = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
LIST_INSERT_HEAD(&t.bar, item, pointers);
```

This was all taken from the list example in the man pages at http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/queue/

For a full example:
http://infnis.wikidot.com/list-from-sys-queue-h

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a comprehensive usage example for queue based on `<sys/queue.h>` and it seems like the example link is no longer valid .. perhaps do you have an alternate Link ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the man instruction:

> man queue

Or [this site](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/list.3.html)

Comment: Although @tinman has already linked the manual page, this can be a nice answer if you add some text from inside the manual page, or even provide an example, instead of just a link.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).