# Is there any easy way of creating Queues in C

Tags: c, data-structures, containers

I've being doing Java for some time and wondering if there's an easy way of creating Queues or similar structures in C? I need to create a buffer that will remove the contents when I need it and be able to add contents to the end of it?

Comment: Typically a queue can be implemented using a double-linked list. But a single-linked list will work too, if you keep track of both the head and the tail of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this suite of data structures and been happy with the results:

http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/utlist.html

The approach of using macros in a header file makes it quite lightweight and straightforward to incorporate into your projects

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in support for Queues, Lists or Maps in C. You need to either find a third party library for it or write one yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're coming from a Java background, you'll find C++ to have more similarities to it than plain C. In the C++ standard template library, there is already a [Queue class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue), which should be about the most efficient Queue you can possibly implement in C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to write it yourself or look for an implementation in the internet. Compared to Java the C standard library is very limited.

On the other hand, implementing such a basic data structure is really simple and there is a lot of documentation available about efficient implementations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux or BSD (including MacOS), you can use [`#include <sys/queue.h>`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sys/queue.h).
Also see

- http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/queue/
- [How to use list from sys/queue.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627099/)

If you are using windows, you can copy the header and edit it to be independent (if necessary).